# In Angular 6, after POSTing big file in Mozilla RAM usage skyrockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, post, mozilla

I have an Angular 6 app that uploads one file using POST:

submit-form.component.html

```
<input type="file" id="file" (change)="onFileChange($event.target.files)">
<button (click)="uploadFile()"> Upload </button>
```

submit-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpResponse, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';

import { FileService } from '../file.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-submit-form',
    templateUrl: './submit-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./submit-form.component.css']
})
export class SubmitFormComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor( private fileService: FileService) { }

    file_to_upload: File;

    onFileChange(files: FileList) {
        this.file_to_upload = files.item(0);
    }

    uploadFile() {
        this.fileService.uploadFile(this.file_to_upload).subscribe(
            (event) => {
                if (event.type == HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                    const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
                    console.log(`Uploading - %${percentDone}...`);
                } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log('File completely loaded!');
                }
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log('Upload Error', JSON.stringify(err));
            }, () => {
                console.log('Done uploading file!');
            }
        );
    }
}
```

file.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FileService {
    private uploadUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/upload';
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    uploadFile(file: File): Observable<any> {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file_to_upload', file, file.name);

        var params = new HttpParams();
        var httpOptions = {
            params: params,
            reportProgress: true
        };

        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.uploadUrl, formData, httpOptions);
        return this.http.request(req);
    }
}
```

And Node.JS server that saves that file using multer:

server.js

```
const http = require('http')
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')
const multer = require('multer')
const express = require('express')

const router = express()
const serverPort = 4200;

router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, 'data/upload/'),
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log('Upload file ', file)
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage});


router.post('/upload', upload.single('file_to_upload'), (req, res) => {
    res.json({'Code': 200, 'Message': 'Success'});
});

router.listen(serverPort, () => console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${serverPort}/`));
```

On Mozilla it works perfectly with small files (<500MB), but when I upload something bigger, the browser freezes between `Uploading - 100%` and `File completely loaded!`, rapidly raises it's memory consumption by approximately 1.5x file size and then instantly drops back down, outputting `File completely loaded!` and `Done uploading file!` (judging by `data/upload/` folder, the file finishes uploading somewhere at the beginning of a memory spike). On Chrome file size does not matter - it always works properly (even with >3GB files).

If I use HTML's `<form>` for file upload, like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:4200/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_to_upload" >
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

...then in both browsers there are no sudden memory spikes. So, what's going on?